# Pandas DataFrame.plot not setting xlim and ylim properly

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I am plotting a large dataset using `dataframe.plot()` in `pandas`. Dataset contains data in `csv` format. As per [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html), I specify `xlim` and `ylim` as arg in `df.plot` as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv(myfile) #contains 2 columns, Time in ms and Voltage in mV
xlabel = "Time in ms"
ylabel = "Volate in mV"
xlim = [0,100]
ylim = [0,8]
df.plot(x = "Time", xlabel= xlabel, ylabel=ylabel, xlim = xlim, ylim = ylim, kind="line")
plt.show()
```

Now the axes take the `xlim` and `ylim` values accordingly but the figure does not scale to these values and plot shows some part of of graph but not the area defined by 'xlim' and 'ylim'.

Without `xlim` set:

[image: Image without Xlim]

with `xlim`set:

[image: Figure with xlim]

I expected to focus on the spike in figure. Do I have to "shuffle" the plot in some way? I have tried `plt.autofocus` but that ignores all `xlim` and `ylim` values  and shows whole figure anyways.

My Dataframe looks something like ([sample files here](https://github.com/regmibijay/opencarp-analyzer/tree/main/samples)):

```
      Time          V
0      0.0 -78.947773
1      1.0 -79.182998
2      2.0 -79.382532
3      3.0 -79.551480
4      4.0 -79.694185
..     ...        ...
496  496.0 -80.434649
497  497.0 -80.435128
498  498.0 -80.435604
499  499.0 -80.436079
500  500.0 -80.436551

[501 rows x 2 columns]
```

Matplotlib Version : 3.4.1 and Pandas 1.2.3

Comment: I used some dummy data and couldn't reproduce locally. One odd thing is that your code shows `xlim = [0,100]` but the plot shows 0 to 120. Is your code actually `xlim = [0,120]` or is that another unexpected issue? `[0,120]` seems better anyway, given location of your spike.

Comment: oh it is another dataset i have, I just wrote `[0,100]`as an example of how i was passing data, it is the same issue.

Comment: What's your `pd.__version__` and `matplotlib.__version__`?

Comment: pandas is 1.2.3 and matplotlib 3.4.1

Comment: Hmm those are my exact versions too. I don't know, hopefully someone else will have an idea.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts @tdy, I tried this on 2 pcs with windows and debian and on one raspberry pi and the issue exists all across devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a bug with `pandas.DataFrame.plot()`, after creating an [issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/40781) on GitHub, we have identified the cause. `df.plot()` was accepting an array without proof checking the elements for `float` or `int` dtype. I have created a [pull request](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/40889) to address the issue and should be fixed with `v1.3.0`.

Meanwhile if you are setting `xlim` or `ylim`,
make sure each element in the range is in `int` or `float` type.

I was using `argparse` to get user data and collecting data as

```
parser = ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-xlim", help="Limit for x-Axis, start and end separated by space.", nargs="+")
args = parser.parse_args()
```

which would create an array `args.xlim` with string values causing this bug. I wrote a function to proofcheck value as

```
def is_int(s):
     try:
        int(s)
        return True
     except ValueError:
        return False

def is_float(s):
     try:
        float(s)
        return True
     except ValueError:
        return False

def check_number(s):
    if is_int(s):
        return int(s)
    elif is_float(s):
        return float(s)
    else:
        raise ArgumentTypeError("not a valid int or float number.")
```

which I can bind to check user input in argparse as

```
parser.add_argument("-xlim", help="Limit for x-Axis, start and end separated by space.", nargs="+", type= check_number)
```